# How to bind SharedPreference to xml layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have a `WeatherData` class which I populate after receiving weather update by REST API calling. I save the `WeatherData` fields in `SharedPreferences`.

Now there is an `fragment` which shows this data on UI. I am thinking to bind the `WeatherData` class to UI. I need that if there is change in any `WeatherData` in `SharedPreferences`, I will update the UI immidiately.

How can I bind the `SharedPreference` to an `XML` layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

```
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                    //update my layout
                }
            });
```

Comment: Don't create the listener this way.  Save a reference to it.  The docs for [`registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)) warn that "The preference manager does not currently store a strong reference to the listener. You must store a strong reference to the listener, or it will be susceptible to garbage collection."

Answer (score 0):

Define the following variable

`public static ObservableInt someCounter = new ObservableInt(getPrefs().getInt("some_counter", 0)) {
        @Override
        public void set(int value) {
            super.set(value);
            getPrefs().edit().putInt("some_counter", value).commit(); (apply() might be more suitable depending on your use)
        }
    };`

Then import the class containing that static variable in your xml layout and reference it like you would any other observable

I wrote a post that covers this in a bit more depth.
https://mpetersen3.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/data-binding-with-shared-prefs/